# Take a picture and saved it in /data/data

Tags: android

I have this code to take a picture and save the picture in `/data/data/...`, but after taking the picture I get `Image saved to: /media/external/images/media/a_number`. I have checked the `/data/data/...` directory and the picture file is not there.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File fileUri = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "INSTALLATION.jpg");

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name


    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
  //...
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing it right.  I think the directory returned by getFilesDir is device dependent.  What are you using?

Comment: I too have same problem : Reason is expect App no-one can write into app private area. I would suggest used app external private area which is world readable and writable i.e  /storage/emulated/0/Android/<your package name>/files/

Answer (score 1):

Third-party camera apps have no rights to write to your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

You are welcome to try writing a `ContentProvider` that supports the streaming API and supports writing to your internal storage, then use a `content://` `Uri` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. I haven't tried this, so I don't know how well it works, and I suspect many camera apps won't expect a `content://` `Uri` there.

Otherwise, your options are:

- Give the third-party camera app a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), then copy the file yourself to internal storage, or
- Do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, but instead use the `Camera` and/or `camera2` APIs to take a picture directly in your app

Comment: Please explain this "Do not use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, but instead use the Camera and/or camera2 APIs to take a picture directly in your app".

Comment: @comonsWare Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, but I didn't have any problem to save a text file for example. I mean in the directory outpputed by `getFilesDir()`. So, why saving a picture file is not possible?

Comment: Here is the code to save a text file I mentioned in my previous comment: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/ae8aa0bab38a0c5f2c09

Comment: @ziiweb: That is *your* code in *your* app running in *your* process. An `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request is going to start up *somebody else's* app, running in *somebody else's* process. That app, in that process, has no access to your app's portion of internal storage.